# Passing Strong Parameters as JSON in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to pass some nested parameters as JSON for my create action in Rails 4.1.0.

My Controller has :

```
def create
  debugger
  invoice = @user.invoices.new(invoice_params)

  if invoice.save
    render head: 201, location: invoice
  else
    render json: invoice.errors, status: 422
  end
end

def invoice_params
  params.require(:invoice).permit(:document_no, :customer_id, :currency_id,
      :date, :due_date, :notes, :total, :tax_total, :grand_total, :invoice_status_id,
      invoice_lines: [:product_id, :description, :quantitiy, :price])
end
```

If I check the sent parameters by using debugger :

```
(byebug) params
{{"invoice":{"document_no":"A-500001","customer_id":1,"currency_id":1,
"date":"2014-09-20","due_date":"2014-09-20","notes":"dasdfsdf",
"total":100,"tax_total":18,"grand_total":118,"invoice_status_id":1,
"invoice_lines":"=>{"product_id":1,"quantity":1,"price":200}"=>{}}=>nil}}, 
"format"=>:json, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"api/v1/invoices"}
```

Just to mention: I cleared the backslashes from the output above just before I posted here.

My integration test code :

```
require 'test_helper'

class CreatingInvoiceTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @user = User.create!(username: 'foo@example.com', password: '123456')
  end

  test 'Creating Invoice' do

    post('/api/v1/invoices', {
      invoice: {
        document_no: 'A-500001',
        customer_id: 1,
        currency_id: 1,
        date: Time.now,
        due_date: Time.now,
        notes: 'dasdfsdf',
        total: 100,
        tax_total: 18,
        grand_total: 118,
        invoice_status_id: 1,
        invoice_lines: [{product_id: 1, quantity: 1, price: 200}]
      }
    }.to_json,
    {'Authorization'=> token_header(@user.token)})

    assert_equal 201, response.status
    assert_equal Mime::JSON, response.content_type

  end
end
```

My model has :

```
has_many :invoice_lines
accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_lines
```

I am having the error below:

`` CreatingInvoiceTest#test_Creating_Invoice:
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: invoice
    app/controllers/api/v1/invoices_controller.rb:29:in `invoice_params'
    app/controllers/api/v1/invoices_controller.rb:9:in `create'
    test/integration/creating_invoice_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:CreatingInvoiceTest>' ``

**I cannot see what I am missing here.**

Comment: parameter `invoice_lines` should be renamed to `invoice_licens_attributes` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: ```invoice_lines_attributes:``` Fixed my problem thanks a lot.